# Aligning first table column with left page margin

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove all space between the left page margin and the content of the first table column without affecting the rest of the table spacing. Is that possible? The problem with setting `border-collapse: collapse` is that it affects the whole table.

Comment: Could you post your html here, it would provide clue to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

see this example to achieve what I think you want:

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
<table border="1" style="margin-left:-3px">
<tr><td style="margin:0px;padding:0px">a</td><td>b</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

notice that the table has a negative margin, you should change that to whatever value suits your design.

Comment: It's the space between the left edge of the table and the content of the first column I want to get rid of. The table itself has no default margin or padding.

Comment: did you try setting "padding-left:0" to the <td> elements of the column?

Comment: Yes, but that alone is not enough.

Comment: I updated the answer. I suggest using a negative margin for the table

Comment: Andrei, thanks for your effort but setting a negative margin in this manner is not a real solution since the needed value is browser dependent.